# JXL not writing more than 1 row to XLS file

Tags: java, jxl

I'm using JAVA with JXL and am trying to write the results of my program to an XLS file.

The code I've written is as below.

The problem I'm facing is it writes only the first row of data in the XLS file.

All other rows are not written in the file.

I'm successfully able to display all the records in the console and also able to write them to an HTML file. So records not being generated or faulty loop is not the issue here.

Can someone please help identify the problem and provide a solution?

```
WritableWorkbook resultWorkbbook = null;
try {
    RESULT_FILE_LOCATION = resultlocation + "-Results-" + df.format(new Date()) + ".xls";
    resultWorkbbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(RESULT_FILE_LOCATION));
    WritableSheet excelSheet = resultWorkbbook.createSheet("Sheet 1", 0);
    for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
        //Some other operationshere.

        excelSheet.addCell(new Number(0, i, totalCases));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(1, i, testCase));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(2, i, requestURL));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(3, i, requestMethod));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(4, i, requestContentType));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(5, i, requestParameters));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(6, i, expectedMessage));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(7, i, responseStatusLine));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(8, i, headers));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(9, i, responsemsg));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(10, i, caseStatus));

        resultWorkbbook.write();
    }
} catch (WriteException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you put the **write();** method on the loop. It supposed to call if the ***adding of cells*** is done. Try to move the **write();** method outside of the loop.

**BONUS**

Follow it with a **close();** method.

**EDIT**

Here's some code:

```
WritableWorkbook resultWorkbbook = null;
try {
    RESULT_FILE_LOCATION = resultlocation + "-Results-" + df.format(new Date()) + ".xls";
    resultWorkbbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(RESULT_FILE_LOCATION));
    WritableSheet excelSheet = resultWorkbbook.createSheet("Sheet 1", 0);
    for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
        //Some other operationshere.

        excelSheet.addCell(new Number(0, i, totalCases));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(1, i, testCase));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(2, i, requestURL));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(3, i, requestMethod));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(4, i, requestContentType));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(5, i, requestParameters));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(6, i, expectedMessage));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(7, i, responseStatusLine));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(8, i, headers));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(9, i, responsemsg));
        excelSheet.addCell(new Label(10, i, caseStatus));
    }
    resultWorkbbook.write();
    resultWorkbbook.close();
} catch (WriteException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If this still not clear or still not working, I have no other solution for that.

Comment: Please give the corrected code, this makes the answer more clear

Comment: I tried moving the write(); outside of the loop. Got the same result. Why do you think the suggested way would work? does the write(); write all the data collected in the loop all at once?